# Python global variables interfering?

Tags: python, variables, global

so basically this is a part of a little string game I am making, this is really buzzing me out. a player can press "a" or "d" to look left or right in a room to gather clues. if the player has already looked in that place. it pops a message saying "you have already been here"

although, it will go to the correct point once, then the next point will just pop a message saying "you have already been here". example. if i press "a"  then "d"  for "d" it will say i've already been there but i haven't. any help/suggestions??

```
left = 0
right = 0
#Room 1 movements
def roomOneLeft():
    global left
    left = 1
    print '-- You search the rubble and find some cloth'
    return roomOneMoves()

def roomOneRight():
    global right
    right = 1
    print '-- You find a pick under a wooden chair'
    return roomOneMoves()

#room 1 user choose
def roomOneMoves():
    global left
    global right
    move = raw_input("")
    if left == 1:
        print 'you have already been here'
        return roomOneMoves()
    if right == 1:
        print 'you have already been here'
        return roomOneMoves() 
    if move == 'a':
        roomOneLeft()     
    if move == 'd':
        roomOneRight()

roomOneMoves()
```

edit: Thank you all for your help. I am sorry if my code is quite frustrating to look at! got it working now. but only from your help.

Comment: You should really use boolean values (`True` and `False`) for variables that only specify those two states.

Comment: have tried. still no luck =[ press another key will just display the "you have already been here"

Comment: Dude, all your `return` statements are recursive - If someone presses `a` 2000 times he's going to hit the maximum recursion depth. Read about event loops please...

Comment: @user1947560 The boolean value comment was not supposed to solve your problem (it would have been an answer then) but a *comment* on what you should improve to make your intention more clear.

Comment: Apart from the observed bug, look hard at the way `roomOneMoves` is called. If you follow the flow through your code, `roomOneMoves` not only never returns (which makes it a game), but also keeps recursively calling itself, which eventually byte (harhar) you in the proverbial behind ;)

Answer (score 3):

Although there are plenty of things one could say are 'iffy' about your code, your issues comes from the fact that both `left` and `right` are checked regardless of the move the player makes. If you press 'a' `left` becomes 1. Pressing 'd' after it will check for `left` being 1 and print the message.

Comment: ohh.. I did not even think of that! sorry. i'm reaaaally noob with it. just started python yesterday. how would one fix this?

Comment: Something like this should do:

`if move == 'a':
  try_visit_room(current_room_number - 1)
elif move == 'd':
  # Same for room no. + 1`

where try_visit_room looks like this:

`def try_visit_room(room_number):
  if is_room_visited(room_number):
    print('you already visited room number', room_number)
  else:
    visit_room(room_number)`

to keep track of what rooms are visited, a list or set would be useful:

`visited_rooms = []

def visit_room(room_number):
  visited_rooms.append(room_number)
  # do other stuff here

def is_room_visited(room_number):
  return room_number in visited_rooms`

Answer (score 2):

Walk through the code:

1. We call `roomOneMoves()`
2. User presses `a`, move becomes `'a'`
3. `left` is not `1`, so we don't enter that branch of the if.
4. `right` is not `1` so we don't enter that branch of the if.
5. `move` *is* `'a'` so we call `roomOneLeft()`
6. `left` becomes `1`, we print a message, and call `roomOneMoves()` again.
7. The user presses `d`, `move` becomes `'d'`
8. `left` is now 1, so we print a message and call `roomOneMoves()` again.

In other words, you're checking if you've been to a room and bailing out, before you decide *which* room the user actually wants to go to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check your move until it's too late. Observe:

```
move = raw_input("")
if left == 1:
    print 'you have already been here'
    return roomOneMoves()
if right == 1:
    print 'you have already been here'
    return roomOneMoves() 
if move == 'a':
    roomOneLeft()     
if move == 'd':
    roomOneRight()
```

You only want to evaluate the `left == 1` part *if the user actually goes left*, don't you? So instead, nest the if statements, like this:

```
move = raw_input("")
if move == 'a':
    if left:
        print 'you have already been here'
        return roomOneMoves()
    roomOneLeft()
if move == 'd':
    if right:
        print 'you have already been here'
        return roomOneMoves() 
    roomOneRight()
```

Also, you should rethink your data structure, and use a dictionary with boolean values or similar instead of global variables. Additionally, since most Python interpreters cannot evaluate [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) efficiently, you may want to use an iterative main loop instead of recursively calling the next functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `roomOneMoves` function:

```
move = raw_input("")
```

First you get the direction from the user; you don’t evaluate it yet though.

```
if left == 1:
    print 'you have already been here'
    return roomOneMoves()
if right == 1:
    print 'you have already been here'
    return roomOneMoves()
```

You check if the user has ever gone left or right before and show the message, and even worse, you start the `roomOneMoves` over again.

```
if move == 'a':
    roomOneLeft()     
if move == 'd':
    roomOneRight()
```

Only after that, you actually evaluate the new direction.

You should first evaluate the new direction and only when evaluating check if the direction was entered once before:

```
move = raw_input("")
if move == 'a':
    if left == 1:
        print 'you have already been here'
    else:
        roomOneLeft()
elif move == 'd':
    if right == 1:
        print 'you have already been here'
    else:
        roomOneRight()
roomOneMoves()
```

Also, you probably want to restart the method unconditionally at the end.

Comment: wow thank you! and where would i put the 'left = left +1' etc?

Comment: @user1947560 What would that be used for? Is that for multiple rooms? If that’s the case, then you should really rethink your design; all rooms should be handled separately, with own state variables for the left/right thing (you could put that perfectly into a class).